# F# - Extending .NET BCL nested classes

Tags: f#

The class System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableHashSet<'t> has a nested type Builder. We can use it in F# without issues.

What I would like to do is add an extension method to that class in F#, like

```
type ImmutableHashSet<'t>.Builder with
    member this.NewMember() = ...
```

but this is not valid F# syntax.

If I extract the fsi I see the following definition

```
namespace System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableHashSet`1
type Builder<'T> = ...
```

however the syntax

```
type ``System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableHashSet`1``.Builder with
    member this.NewMember() = ...
```

is also non valid.

Is there a way to write this extension in F#?

Comment: ```System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableHashSet`1``.Builder<'a> ` works. Nested classes inside generics actually also generic, but language hides this detail

Comment: This is documented in ecma-335 I.10.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back-ticks are confusing the markdown, so to clarify what @JL0PD wrote, the following seems to work:

```ml
open System.Collections.Immutable

type ``ImmutableHashSet`1``.Builder<'a> with
    member _.NewMember() = printfn "Hello world"

let builder = ImmutableHashSet.CreateBuilder<int>()
builder.NewMember()   // Hello world
```

Exposing the mangled name like this is surprising to me, so it's possible that this only works by accident and could change in the future.